# What will happen to a workqueue's work which was in execution, but got preempted somehow?

Tags: linux, multithreading

What will happen to a workqueue's work which was in execution, but got preempted somehow and later `destroy_workqueue` was called on the same workqueue? Will it schedule the thread which was executing the work?

Answer (score 0):

`destroy_workqueue` waits until the workqueue becomes empty, by virtue of calling [`drain_workqueue`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15.2/source/kernel/workqueue.c#L2744).